# Error while reading plist file

Tags: objective-c, plist

When I add a property list in Xcode, my app crashed when we push on the button. I search very much but I didn't found the error; please help me. Here's my viewController.m.But there isn't nil variables... So it's not the problem. 
Here's my plist file:

Root (dictionnary) (12 items)

compteur111 string 1 
compteur222 string 2
compteur333 string 3
compteur444 string 4
compteur555 string 5
compteur666 string 6
name1 string 11
name2 string 12
name3 string 13
name4 string 14
name5 string 15
name6 string 16

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

//Synthétisation des propriétés
@synthesize labelValeurCompteur1;
@synthesize labelValeurCompteur2;
@synthesize labelValeurCompteur3;
@synthesize labelValeurCompteur4;
@synthesize labelValeurCompteur5;
@synthesize labelValeurCompteur6;

@synthesize nameCompteur1;
@synthesize nameCompteur2;
@synthesize nameCompteur3;
@synthesize nameCompteur4;
@synthesize nameCompteur5;
@synthesize nameCompteur6;

@synthesize compteur11;
@synthesize compteur22;
@synthesize compteur33;
@synthesize compteur44;
@synthesize compteur55;
@synthesize compteur66;

@synthesize compteur01;
@synthesize compteur02;
@synthesize compteur03;
@synthesize compteur04;
@synthesize compteur05;
@synthesize compteur06;

-(IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender
{
    [labelValeurCompteur1 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur2 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur3 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur4 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur5 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur6 resignFirstResponder];

    [nameCompteur1 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur2 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur3 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur4 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur5 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur6 resignFirstResponder];    
}   

-(IBAction)numeroCompteur:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"> numeroCompteur");

    [labelValeurCompteur1 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur2 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur3 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur4 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur5 resignFirstResponder];
    [labelValeurCompteur6 resignFirstResponder];

    [nameCompteur1 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur2 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur3 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur4 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur5 resignFirstResponder];
    [nameCompteur6 resignFirstResponder];  


int variableDebutCompteur1 = [[labelValeurCompteur1 text] intValue];
int variableDebutCompteur2 = [[labelValeurCompteur2 text] intValue];
int variableDebutCompteur3 = [[labelValeurCompteur3 text] intValue];
int variableDebutCompteur4 = [[labelValeurCompteur4 text] intValue];
int variableDebutCompteur5 = [[labelValeurCompteur5 text] intValue];
int variableDebutCompteur6 = [[labelValeurCompteur6 text] intValue];    

compteur1.value = variableDebutCompteur1;
compteur2.value = variableDebutCompteur2;
compteur3.value = variableDebutCompteur3;
compteur4.value = variableDebutCompteur4;
compteur5.value = variableDebutCompteur5;
compteur6.value = variableDebutCompteur6;

labelValeurCompteur1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", variableDebutCompteur1];
labelValeurCompteur2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", variableDebutCompteur2];
labelValeurCompteur3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", variableDebutCompteur3];
labelValeurCompteur4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", variableDebutCompteur4];
labelValeurCompteur5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", variableDebutCompteur5];
labelValeurCompteur6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", variableDebutCompteur6];

compteur11 = labelValeurCompteur1.text;
compteur22 = labelValeurCompteur2.text;
compteur33 = labelValeurCompteur3.text;
compteur44 = labelValeurCompteur4.text;
compteur55 = labelValeurCompteur5.text;
compteur66 = labelValeurCompteur6.text;    

{
    NSLog(@" - Writing DataP.plist Counters");
    NSString *error;
    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataP.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects: compteur11, compteur22, compteur33, compteur44, compteur55, compteur66, nil]
                                                          forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"compteur111", @"compteur222", @"compteur333", @"compteur444", @"compteur555", @"compteur666", nil]];
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict
                                                                   format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                         errorDescription:&error];
    if(plistData) {
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
    else {
        [error release];
    }        
}

nameCompteur1.text = nameCompteur1.text;
nameCompteur2.text = nameCompteur2.text;
nameCompteur3.text = nameCompteur3.text;
nameCompteur4.text = nameCompteur4.text;
nameCompteur5.text = nameCompteur5.text;
nameCompteur6.text = nameCompteur6.text;

{
    NSLog(@" - Writing DataP.plist Labels");
    NSString *error;
    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataP.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects: compteur01, compteur02, compteur03, compteur04, compteur05, compteur06, nil]
                                                          forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"name1", @"name2", @"name3", @"name4", @"name5", @"name6", nil]];
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict
                                                                   format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                         errorDescription:&error];
    if(plistData) {
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"  ! Error writeToFile:plistData:labels");
        [error release];
    }
}

NSLog(@"< numeroCompteur");
}

-(IBAction)changerValeurCompteurUn:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    int variableDebutCompteur1 = [sender value];
    [labelValeurCompteur1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)variableDebutCompteur1]];
}
-(IBAction)changerValeurCompteurDeux:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    int valeurCompteur2 = [sender value];
    [labelValeurCompteur2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)valeurCompteur2]];
}
-(IBAction)changerValeurCompteurTrois:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    int valeurCompteur3 = [sender value];
    [labelValeurCompteur3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)valeurCompteur3]];
}
-(IBAction)changerValeurCompteurQuatre:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    int valeurCompteur4 = [sender value];
    [labelValeurCompteur4 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)valeurCompteur4]];
}
-(IBAction)changerValeurCompteurCinq:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    int valeurCompteur5 = [sender value];
    [labelValeurCompteur5 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)valeurCompteur5]];
}
-(IBAction)changerValeurCompteurSix:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    int valeurCompteur6 = [sender value];
    [labelValeurCompteur6 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)valeurCompteur6]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bois.JPG"]]];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"> viewDidLoad");
        if (self) {
            NSString *errorDesc = nil;
            NSPropertyListFormat format;
            NSString *plistPath;
            NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                      NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataP.plist"];
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
                plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataP" ofType:@"plist"];
            }
            else
                NSLog(@"  ! Error reading DataP.plist");
            NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
            NSDictionary *tempR = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                                  propertyListFromData:plistXML
                                                  mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                                  format:&format
                                                  errorDescription:&errorDesc];
            if (!tempR) {
                NSLog(@"  ! Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
            }
            self.compteur11 = [tempR objectForKey:@"compteur111"];
            labelValeurCompteur1.text = compteur11;
            self.compteur22 = [tempR objectForKey:@"compteur222"];
            labelValeurCompteur2.text = compteur22;
            self.compteur33 = [tempR objectForKey:@"compteur333"];
            labelValeurCompteur3.text = compteur33;
            self.compteur44 = [tempR objectForKey:@"compteur444"];
            labelValeurCompteur4.text = compteur44;
            self.compteur55 = [tempR objectForKey:@"compteur555"];
            labelValeurCompteur5.text = compteur55;
            self.compteur66 = [tempR objectForKey:@"compteur666"];
            labelValeurCompteur6.text = compteur66;

             self.compteur01 = [tempR objectForKey:@"name1"];
             nameCompteur1.text = compteur01;
             self.compteur02 = [tempR objectForKey:@"name2"];
             nameCompteur2.text = compteur02;
             self.compteur03 = [tempR objectForKey:@"name3"];
             nameCompteur3.text = compteur03;
             self.compteur04 = [tempR objectForKey:@"name4"];
             nameCompteur4.text = compteur04;
             self.compteur05 = [tempR objectForKey:@"name5"];
             nameCompteur5.text = compteur05;
             self.compteur06 = [tempR objectForKey:@"name6"];
             nameCompteur6.text = compteur06;
        }
    NSLog(@"< viewDidLoad");
}    

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

here's my crash log:

```
2013-03-31 20:08:20.723 iCounterClick[28622:c07]   ! Error reading DataP.plist
2013-03-31 20:08:21.739 iCounterClick[28622:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c96012 0x10d3e7e 0x1ca1737 0x1cc28c2 0x2214 0x10e7705 0x1b2c0 0x257a64 0x10e7705 0x1b2c0 0x1b258 0xdc021 0xdc57f 0xdb6e8 0x4acef 0x4af02 0x28d4a 0x1a698 0x1bf1df9 0x1bf1ad0 0x1c0bbf5 0x1c0b962 0x1c3cbb6 0x1c3bf44 0x1c3be1b 0x1bf07e3 0x1bf0668 0x17ffc 0x1c9d 0x1bc5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code that you're asking others to read through and debug. What steps have you taken to narrow down the source of the problem yourself? The exception message gives you quite a bit of information. What have you done with that?

Comment: Make minimal Your question and show the plist. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **@JoshCaswell**. Based on your question is quite difficult to understand what is going on.

Usually similar errors are due to `nil` values. An example of a similar error could be derived from the following snippet

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myObject, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"myObjectKey", nil]];
```

If `myObject` is `nil`, bum! You will receive an exception meaning the objects array is of size 0 while the keys array is of size 1.

**My suggestions**

Try to remove some code and show us the plist file you want to load.

**My notes**

Reading very quickly your code I saw something strange. In particular, why do you use these lines in `viewDidLoad` method?

```
self = [super init];
NSLog(@"> viewDidLoad");
    if (self) {
```

Use them in your initializer.

`viewDidLoad` method has a specific meaning: You are sure the `view` associated with a controller has been correctly loaded in memory and you can perform additional customizations.

**Edit**

As previously said, you cannot insert `nil` obects within a dictionary. One simple test is the following:

```
if(compteur11) {
    NSLog(@"compteur11 is %@");
} else {
    NSLog(@"compteur11 is nil");
}
```

What log do you receive?

Comment: Excuse me, here's the following code:

            NSString *error;
        NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataP.plist"];
        NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

Comment: @user2187565 Please edit your question and put the code there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: compteur11, compteur22, compteur33, compteur44, compteur55, compteur66, compteur01, compteur02, compteur03, compteur04, compteur05, compteur06, nil]
                                                              forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"compteur111", @"compteur222", @"compteur333", @"compteur444", @"compteur555", @"compteur666", @"name1", @"name2", @"name3", @"name4", @"name5", @"name6", nil]];
  

thank your for your answers

Comment: Ok, but I'm new and I must wait 5 hours to post another question so I posted comments with the code, sorry

Comment: No. Just edit the question you created. I think you are able to do it. Anyway, one of the objects `compteur11, compteur22, compteur33, compteur44, compteur55, compteur66, compteur01, compteur02, compteur03, compteur04, compteur05, compteur06` is `nil`. That's the problem.

Comment: @user2187565 I added an edit for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: I added an edit in my question

Comment: I receive "compteur 11 is nil" but in the property list, it's 1.. Is it possible that the app not found the plist? Or can't read the plist?